# My animations from blender won't transfer over correctly

Tags: animation, 3d, game-development, blender, godot

I am trying to make animations for a tank tread for a game but it doesn't seem to work right. I suspect it is related to the fact that I wrapped the treads around a Bezier curve to make it work. I also have a video if anyone is willing to help https://youtu.be/Mn6v6jiUSSk

I tried importing in different file formats to see if that would effect it. Many of them just did not have an animation at all

Comment: I believe the kind of animation is just not supported. As far as I know, skeletal animations and blend shape animations should work. Thus, the best I can suggest to try to recreate the animation as one of those.

Comment: Does that mean I will have to completely remake the animation?

Comment: That is correct. Addendum: perhaps you might want to bring the issue to the Godot github, for instance in discussions: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions

Comment: Honestly I don't really understand enough about what is going wrong in the first place to make a post that would mean anything

Comment: I believe you have enough to make a bug report in https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues (namely, you have a case that can be reproduced, and you can show the result you expected and what you actually got). However, I'm suggesting to post in discussions https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions because I believe this should be a feature proposal (which go in https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues) but discussion does not have an strict format. Anyway, assuming you need a solution now, instead of Waiting for Godot, yes, remake the animation by other means.